# Get Tweets in English only using Node Red

Tags: twitter, node-red

I build a small project on node-red to retrieve tweets using the Twitter Source node.

I am only getting the tweets and putting them in a Cloudant Database.

[image]

What I want now is to select only the tweets that are in English Language. Can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages emitted by the Twitter node have a field called lang which you can use to filter.

Add a function node between the twitter node and the cloudant node with the following:

```
if (msg.lang === 'en') {
  return msg;
} else {
  return null;
}
```

This should throw away any none English tweets